# Is there a way to get swagger ui html from io.swagger.models.Swagger?

Tags: java, merge, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

OK, I have a number of **io.swagger.models.Swagger** objects, I have merged these into one new, super Swagger. Now I want the super html. How can I get this? Note, in order to get each of my Swagger definitions, I used new SwaggerParser().read("pathToSwagger"). So, that's an example of getting a Swagger object from the Swagger source, now I need the opposite, namely, to produce Swagger source from a **io.swagger.models.Swagger** object. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code. From `JSONObject`, you will get the Swagger json, which can be further used in the HTML.

```java
public JSONObject getSwaggerJson(Swagger swagger) throws ServiceApiException {
    try {
        // Re-parse as JsonObject to ensure ordering of definitions and paths.
        // TODO: make this optional (see limberest.yaml comments in limberest-demo)
        JsonObject swaggerJson = new JsonObject(Json.mapper().writeValueAsString(swagger));
        if (swaggerJson.has("definitions"))
            swaggerJson.put("definitions", new JsonObject(swaggerJson.getJSONObject("definitions").toString()));
        if (swaggerJson.has("paths"))
            swaggerJson.put("paths", new JsonObject(swaggerJson.getJSONObject("paths").toString()));
        return swaggerJson;
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new ServiceApiException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Source : https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=io.swagger.models.Swagger

Answer (score 1):

I know one interest open source project [j2html](https://github.com/tipsy/j2html).
There, the formation of the html document is performed in interesting way. May be it'll help you to create one html from super swagger object.